# 'Sys is undefined' error javascript error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I've tried every solution I've found through Google, and I'm currently at a loss.

I have several projects which were created for .Net 2.0 and IIS6 Server 2003 32 bit, and are being migrated to IIS7 Server 2008 64 bit (I'm new to both IIS7 and Server '08). Right now any page that utilizes .Net AJAX is getting this 'Sys is undefined error' after migration. When I view source and try to view any *.axd file, I get a 404.

I've checked that my web.config has all the appropriate sections., with all "Version" attributes set to 1.0.61025.0 since I'm not currently upgrading from .Net 2.0. The Virtual Directories are created as applications, and the App Pool is set to .Net 2.0 Integrated.

I've checked that the *.axd Handler Mappings are there and set to "Unspecified Path Type". Also there are the appropriate *_AppService.axd and ScriptResource.axd mappings.

I'm not making any custom javascript references to Sys.

I've already tried repairing/reinstalling .Net on the server, and running aspnet_regiis via the command line.

I've also tried creating "blank" WebResource.axd and ScriptResource.axd files to put them in the project. While they eliminate the 'Sys is undefined' error, it also breaks functionality within any page looking for that file.

Do I have any other options? Did I miss something else, or did I make a mistake in the steps I've already taken? Any insight you guys could provide is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you installed [ASP.NET AJAX 1.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ca9d90fa-e8c9-42e3-aa19-08e2c027f5d6&displaylang=en)?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed replay, I though I'd receive an email for comments as well as answers. Yes ASP .Net AJAX is installed on the server, although I didnt do it myself. Thinking it might be the problem however, I attempted repairing it, as well as removing it and reinstalling it, and the error still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `ScriptResource.axd` Handler mapping resolved my problem once.

Also we had done this at that time,

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Hope that helps you out    (^.^)

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply! I attempted your solution, and it didnt seem to make a difference. Would you happen to have any other ideas? I have a feeling that it's something minor that I'm totally missing since I've tried every solution I've found.